# I want my onPressed method to open the keyboard of Spinbox

Tags: flutter, dart, spinbox

I use spinbox to set the number of break time in minutes. If you tap on the number a keyboard opens, and you can set your number. How do I open the Same keyboard of my spinbox, while pressing on the ElevatedButton?

I prepared the code for testing below,
and I added (flutter_spinbox: ^0.4.0) to pubspec.yaml

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_spinbox/flutter_spinbox.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  int breaktime = 60;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text("SpinBox")),
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Container(
              child: ElevatedButton(
                child: Text(
                  'Break in minutes',
                ),
                onPressed: () => {}, 
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              height: 35,
              child: SpinBox(
                min: 0,
                max: 120,
                value: 60,
                onChanged: (value) => breaktime = value.toInt(),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, based on `SpinBox` [sources](https://github.com/jpnurmi/flutter_spinbox), there's no easy way to do it.

Thankfully, there's a workaround:

```dart
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final spinBoxKey = GlobalKey();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: SpinBox(
            key: spinBoxKey,
          ),
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () {
            final focusNode = (spinBoxKey.currentState as dynamic).focusNode as FocusNode;
            focusNode.requestFocus();
          },
          child: Icon(Icons.keyboard),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

- assign a `GlobalKey` to the widget (SpinBox in this case)
- onClick:

  - extract `BaseSpinBoxState` state using key that you've created before
  - `BaseSpinBoxState` has `focusNode` getter, call it and invoke `requestFocus` on it